# quantity comparative test on GRE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gre-exam

i would like to compare two quantity,first  is

$-3^4$    and $(-3)^4$,second one is clearly $81$,but what about second  on?is  it $-3\cdot-3\cdot-3\cdot-3$ ? $-3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3$?there could be such kind of question on GRE exam and i should know answer on this question,please help me

Comment: If you know the second is *clearly* 81, by the same logic you should know the first. But this excercise is about signs, and the fact that $+>-$ (in rough terms).As a side note: When you talk about several objects, use the plural, as in *quantities*.Also, start the sentences with a capital letter, and use capitals in every *I* you use (I know english can be very egocentric) .

Comment: If you do not use english as your native language (as it seems you do, otherwise this would just be about laziness), I hope this will help you in your  GRE exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that exponents have higher precedence than the unary operation of negation, so:
$$
-3^4=-(3^4)=-(3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3)=-(81)=-81
$$
while on the other hand:
$$
(-3)^4=(-3) \cdot (-3) \cdot (-3) \cdot (-3)=81
$$

If you've heard of the mnemonic device [BEDMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), you can think of the unary operation of a negation such as $-x$ as really being the binary operation of the subtraction $0-x$. Hence, since "E" comes before "S", we apply the exponent first before the negative sign (that is, before subtracting it from $0$).

Comment: so it means that $-$ sign will stay unchanged?

Comment: Yes, we temporarily ignore the negative sign when evaluating $-3^4$. After evaluating $3^4$, we finish by negating the result. So for example:
$$
-(-2)^3=-(-8)=8
$$